# How can I rewind memories during memory remix?

Tags: remember-me

I've gotten to the Olga Sedova memory remix after she's tracked me down at Tommy's bar - The Leaking Brain - and caught me off guard.

Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to work out what to do? The on screen prompt says:

> Rotate the mouse anti-clockwise until you find a memory glitch. Hold the Left Mouse Button to rewind faster.

Rotate the mouse? *Really?*

Rotating the mouse just seems to have the effect of making the game wonder what the hell I'm telling it to do with a 'pause' and 'rewind' icon flashing in the middle of the screen and the memory not rewinding. I feel I'm missing something really obvious - how can I rewind memories during memory remix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't actually rotate the mouse.  Instead you should essentially be drawing a circle with the mouse.  Think about turning a jog wheel (circular dial) with you index finger.  Clockwise advances a track, counter-clockwise reverses it.

Comment: I think I'm just going to plug in a gamepad and be done with it, this has to be the silliest thing I've ever come across...

Answer (score 0):

Yep, draw a circle, counter-clockwise. Draw it really carefully until you see something flashing. Rest is self-explanatory.